# Where do I have to undefine queue when using multithread

Tags: multithreading, perl, queue

I have a script that creates a queue and some workers that are reading its jobs from the queue. My problem is now that the script does not terminate and call printData() because the threads are idling. And this because I have not set the queue to undef.

I have tried many different ways but all lead to various problems.

- Either queue was terminated although there were still jobs in the queue
- Or there were no jobs in the queue at the moment although there was still a thread working and trying to push new work into the queue.

I use the following code

```
# -------------------------
# Main
# -------------------------
my @threads = map threads->create(\&doOperation), 1 .. $maxNumberOfParallelJobs;
pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($directory);
#$worker->enqueue((undef) x $maxNumberOfParallelJobs);
$_->join for @threads;

sub pullDataFromDbWithDirectory {
    my $_dir = $_[0];

    if ($itemCount <= $maxNumberOfItems) {
        my @retval = grep { /^Dir|^File/ } qx($omnidb -filesystem $filesystem  '$label'  -listdir '$_dir');

        foreach my $item (@retval) {
            $itemCount++;
            (my $filename = $item) =~ s/^File\s+|^Dir\s+|\n//g;
            my $file = "$_dir/$filename";
            push(@data,$file);

            if ($item =~ /^Dir/) {
                $worker->enqueue($file);
                print "Add $file to queue\n" if $debug;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid();
    do {
       my $folder = $worker->dequeue();
       print "Read $folder from queue with thread $ithread\n" if $debug;
       pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($folder);
   } while ($worker->pending());

   push(@IDLE_THREADS,$ithread);

}
```

EDIT:

I found an ugly solution. Maybe there is better ones? I add the workers into an IDLE array and sleep until all the workers are in there

```
sleep 0.01 while (scalar @IDLE_THREADS < $maxNumberOfParallelJobs);
$worker->enqueue((undef) x $maxNumberOfParallelJobs);
$_->join for @threads;
```

Comment: You can't use `->pending()` without having threads die off prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `->pending()` without having threads die off prematurely. Fix:

```
my $busy: shared = $num_workers;

sub pullDataFromDbWithDirectory {
    my $tid = threads->tid();
    while (defined( my $folder = $q->dequeue() )) {
        { lock $busy; ++$busy; }
        print "Worker thread $tid processing folder $folder.\n" if $debug;
        pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($folder);
        { lock $busy; --$busy; }
    }

    print "Worker thread $tid exiting.\n" if $debug;
}

sleep 0.01 while $q->pending || $busy;
$worker->end();
$_->join for @threads;
```

But that introduces a race condition.

1. A worker thread dequeues the last item currently in the queue
2. main thread checks pending (false)
3. main thread checks number of busy threads (none)
4. main thread signals workers to end
5. All other worker threads exit.
6. The worker that dequeued the item above marks itself busy
7. The worker starts processing last item, tries to adding a bunch of items in the queue and fails.

The dequeuing plus the busy incrementing needs to be atomic, and the pending check plus the busy check needs to be atomic.

That's not possible to do without changing Thread::Queue. You can't just throw a lock around those two piece of code, cause that would prevent the master from checking if all of the threads are idle when one of them is idle.

We need to split `->dequeue` into its waiting component and its dequeuing component. We have the latter (`->dequeue_nb`), so we just need the former.

```
use Thread::Queue 3.01;

sub T_Q_wait {
    my $self = shift;
    lock(%$self);
    my $queue = $$self{'queue'};

    my $count = @_ ? $self->_validate_count(shift) : 1;

    # Wait for requisite number of items
    cond_wait(%$self) while ((@$queue < $count) && ! $$self{'ENDED'});
    cond_signal(%$self) if (@$queue);

    return !$$self{'ENDED'};
}
```

Now we can write the solution:

```
my $busy: shared = 0;

sub pullDataFromDbWithDirectory {
    my $tid = threads->tid();

    WORKER_LOOP:
    while (T_Q_wait($q)) {
        my $folder;

        {
            lock $busy;
            $folder = $q->dequeue_nb();
            next WORKER_LOOP if !defined($folder);
            ++$busy;
        }

        print "Worker thread $tid processing folder $folder.\n" if $debug;
        pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($folder);

        {
            lock $busy;
            --$busy;
            cond_signal($busy) if !$busy;
        }
    }
}

{
    lock $busy;
    cond_wait($busy) while $busy;
    $q->end();
    $_->join() for threads->list();
}
```

The `next` is there in case another thread snagged the work between `wait` and `dequeue_nb`.

Comment: It's completely untested. But any failure should be something simple.